# I can't connect Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4) Touch Smart hp envy i7

Tags: intel-wireless

I can't connect  Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4) in a Touch Smart hp envy i7Core when i put this rfkill list in the terminal say 
        hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes 
Do you konw what is wrong? How i can activate the wirless

Answer (score 0):

Hard block means your switch button is pressed.

try clicking it. it probably is on F12.

I also heard some issues about the hard switch is not working unless pressed on boot up process or while on grub because of misconfigured bus.

Comment: How i can enable by switch a my computer says   wifi disabled by hardware switch                    i tried f12 but i cant

Comment: Hardswitch is unsupported in newer machines. while on boot, just press it once. It shall warn you with change of light on it.

Answer (score 0):

On Dell Inspiron 5220 with Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4), it's on the F2 key. struggled for four hours, hence the post!

buxtor